# How to get a list of values into a flag in Golang?

Tags: go

What is Golang's equivalent of the below python commands ?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="something")
parser.add_argument("-getList1",nargs='*',help="get 0 or more values")
parser.add_argument("-getList2",nargs='?',help="get 1 or more values")
```

I have seen that the flag package allows argument parsing in Golang.
But it seems to support only String, Int or Bool.
How to get a list of values into a flag in this format :

```
go run myCode.go -getList1 value1 value2
```

Answer (score 205):

You can define your own `flag.Value` and use `flag.Var()` for binding it.

The example is [here](http://play.golang.org/p/Ig5sm7jA14).

Then you can pass multiple flags like following:

```
go run your_file.go --list1 value1 --list1 value2
```

UPD: including code snippet right there just in case.

```
package main

import "flag"

type arrayFlags []string

func (i *arrayFlags) String() string {
    return "my string representation"
}

func (i *arrayFlags) Set(value string) error {
    *i = append(*i, value)
    return nil
}

var myFlags arrayFlags

func main() {
    flag.Var(&myFlags, "list1", "Some description for this param.")
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Comment: +1. The `flag.Value()` method can also be used if you want to specify all list elements in one comma separated `string` which `Value()` can split into a slice of `string`s. `flag.Value` and `flag.Var()` is much more general than just using `flag.String()` and `strings.Split()`. Errors reported by `Value()` are also handled automatically by package `flag`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But is it possible to implement it this way : go run my_file.go --list1 value1 value2

Comment: The link is dead now.

Comment: Yep -- looks like it is back now. Before it was returning a server error. Maybe it would be best to include the code snippet here so there isn't the dependency on that site being up.

Comment: @sholsapp updated answer to include the code snippet

Comment: This is such an awesome suggestion which is completely not apparent from official documentation. I wish there was +10. Please consider adding this to official documentation.

Comment: I realize this is 3 years old but this does not fully answer the original question.
You can utilize duplicate flags this way but to my knowledge you cannot perform the original desire: A single flag call with multiple values.  This is a really basic flag operation and I refuse to believe Go doesn't allow it in the standard library

Comment: @KoalaBear the problem with a single flag call with multiple values is it is ambiguous. The same syntax normally means a single flag call with a single value, followed by a single [argument](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Arg). I think the solution in this answer is the best you can hope for.

Comment: The same example with `flag.Set()` and checking out: https://play.golang.org/p/H_IiaBv2TPx

Comment: can we have a default here that is overwritten when the flags are set?

Comment: Note that this answer, in spite of being up-voted so much, does _not_ address the way the OP wishes to do things. Please see the comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672394/1035977 below, which neatly exemplifies how it's properly done.

Answer (score 24):

You can at least have a list of arguments on the end of you command by using the [`flag.Args()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args) function.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var one string

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&one, "o", "default", "arg one")
    flag.Parse()
    tail := flag.Args()
    fmt.Printf("Tail: %+q\n", tail)
}
```

`my-go-app -o 1 this is the rest` will print `Tail: ["this" "is" "the" "rest"]`

Comment: That's exactly the solution I wanted, thx a lot!

Answer (score 17):

Use [flag.String()](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#String) to get the entire list of values for the argument you need and then split it up into individual items with [strings.Split()](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).

Comment: Your approach doesn't allow to pass arguments divided by space like `-opt 1 2 3`.

Comment: @AlexMedveshchek If the argument to the option is truely separated by spaces (e.g. if you typed `foo -opt "1 2 3"`), then of course it works.  If you Pass them as separate arguments to the program (i.e. if you typed `foo -opt 1 2 3`) then of course it can't work at all, even with other strategies, as you cannot distinguish the arguments to the option from other operands following it.  Don't write programs that way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can feed `"1 2 3"` in quotes, and it will work. But it's artificial, and the original question was how to implement argument parsing like it implemented in python's `argparse`, which allows to parse mentioned case. In fact it's really easy to implement: you just need to consume `-opt`'s arguments until you meet some other known option like `-opt2` or the last argument in command line.

Comment: @Alex Medveshchek That's a super shitty way of parsing option arguments because you can't easily have operands after them. Plus it's in violation of the UCB utility guidelines which is a bad thing, too.

Comment: @AlexMedveshchek Indeed! Few people know about them and proceed to design unintuitive command line interfaces due to not following established conventions.

Comment: @AlexMedveshchek [The guidelines in question](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01).

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting. In fact pythonic `argparse` allows to implement this approach and even more. And I've met other cases in my practice when using OG's approach was not sufficient. Anyway, thank you for valuable info.

Comment: When a shell generates operands from a glob or brace expansion before the program is invoked, the output will be space delimited.

Comment: @vdm In that case, each word is passed as a separate operand.   The UCB guidelines with `:` are about lists of tokens passed to options as a single command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a series of integer values at the end of the command line, this helper function will properly convert them and place them in a slice of `int`s:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func GetIntSlice(i *[]string) []int {
    var arr = *i
    ret := []int{}
    for _, str := range arr {
        one_int, _ := strconv.Atoi(str)
        ret = append(ret, one_int)
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    tail := flag.Args()
    fmt.Printf("Tail: %T,  %+v\n", tail, tail)
    intSlice := GetIntSlice(&tail)

    fmt.Printf("intSlice: %T,  %+v\n", intSlice, intSlice)

}

mac:demoProject sx$ go run demo2.go 1 2 3 4
Tail: []string,  [1 2 3 4]
intSlice: []int,  [1 2 3 4]
```