# parse go flags with more than one value

Tags: go

I've the following code and I need to get the values like `val1` and `val2` and `arg1` and `arg2` and print it, I've tried many ways, is it possible ?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    args := strings.Fields("-loc .env -names val1 val2 -tags arg1 arg2")



    FlagSet := flag.NewFlagSet("FlagSet", flag.ContinueOnError)
    loc := FlagSet.String("loc", "", "")
    name := FlagSet.String("names", "", "")
    tags := FlagSet.String("tags", "", "")
    

    FlagSet.Parse(args)

    fmt.Printf("location: %s \n", *loc)
    fmt.Printf("name: %s \n", *name)
    fmt.Printf("tags: %s \n", *tags)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8aN5-0EZ2OT

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322997/how-to-get-a-list-of-values-into-a-flag-in-golang#:~:text=9-,Use%20flag.,Split().&text=You%20can%20at%20least%20have,command%20by%20using%20the%20flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not how flags are parsed by the stdlib flag package: https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax. A flag can have a single argument.

The best you can do is `-loc .env -names "val1 val2" -tags "arg1 arg2"` or `-loc .env -names val1,val2 -tags arg1,arg2`. In the first case the double quotes turn the multiple words into a single command-line argument, and in the second using a comma instead of a space combines the arguments. In both cases you'll have to parse the result into individual arguments, perhaps using `strings.Split`.

Note that you use `strings.Fields` to break your test arguments into space-separated fields, but this ignores quotes, which differs from the behaviour of your command-line.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with command comma and it works but with the double quotes doesnt any idea?

Comment: Yes, because `strings.Fields` doesn't respect quotes. It'll work if you pass in args from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

As shell use space(" ") as separator, it is not a good idea to use space as the separator. Use comma "," as the separator could solve this problem elegantly.

https://play.golang.org/p/xF2N_qnRlwe

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    //NOT GOOD - multiple values (see value1 value2)
    args := strings.Fields(`-loc .env -names val1,val2 -tags arg1,arg2`)

    FlagSet := flag.NewFlagSet("FlagSet", flag.ContinueOnError)
    loc := FlagSet.String("loc", "", "")
    names := FlagSet.String("names", "", "")
    tags := FlagSet.String("tags", "", "")

    FlagSet.Parse(args)

    fmt.Printf("location: %s \n", *loc)
    fmt.Printf("names: %s \n", strings.Split(*names, ","))
    fmt.Printf("tags: %s \n", strings.Split(*tags, ","))
}
```