# How to parse a list of parameters in Golang (multiple duplicate and comma separated)?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I need to parse different parameters in GO (multiple duplicate and comma separated). How can I do it for this example:

`go run ./test.go -param "one, two" -param "tree" -param "four"`

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28323276/9147209) is good but doesn't work for the mentioned example:

`[one, two tree four]`

I.e. it works for the multiple duplicate parameters but doesn't work for the comma separated.

How can I improve the mentioned script to parse several parameters including comma separated to get this (no comma) in the result:

`[one two tree four]`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `Set` method such that it splits its argument at comma and appends the result to the receiver.

```golang
func (i *arrayFlags) Set(value string) error {
    s := strings.Split(value, ",")
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = strings.TrimSpace(s[i])
    }
    *i = append(*i, s...)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have the updated script (https://play.golang.org/p/JhK3_em8WrE) but receiving "13:7: undefined: strings", "15:16: undefined: strings" errors.

Comment: @HeiligOleg [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) is a package, you need to import it to be able to use it, just like you're importing `flag` and `fmt`.